# working with python xml parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from xml.dom import minidom

user_input = raw_input("Enter the path of your file: ")
#f = open(user_input,'r+')
#str(f)
apktool = "/usr/share/apktool/apktool.jar"
os.system(apktool + " d " +  user_input)
base = os.path.basename(user_input)
a = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
#b = os.path.dirname(user_input)
d = os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
#print d
#print a
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0])):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.startswith('AndroidManifest'):
            pth = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,filename))
            print pth
```

`Enter the path of your file: /roo/Desktop/test.apk`

After I run the script the 'pth' output gives the following paths:
`/root/Desktop/test/AndroidManifest.xml` and `/root/Desktop/test/org/AndroidManifest.xml`

However my desired output for 'pth' is `/root/Desktop/test/AndroidManifest.xml`
How do I achieve this?

Comment: ...where is xml used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `root` changes as it goes through the folders.
At some point it becomes `/root/Desktop/test/org/` which is how you get
 `/root/Desktop/test/org/AndroidManifest.xml` as a path when you do the
`pth = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,filename))`

It seems like the path you want is only the very first value of `root`, in which case you can try:
`pth = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0]), filename)`
Which is basically joining the path that you are passing to `os.walk`